# ¿Como guardar dos tablas?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql

Tengo este formulario [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estan son las tablas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es que los Texbox se guarden primero que la tabla, los dos los tengo dentro de un mismo metodo que despues llamo en un boton,

este es el codigo que tengo

```js
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("f_facturas", conexion, transaccion);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Transaction = transaccion;

                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_cliente", Convert.ToString(cliente.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_proveedor", Convert.ToString(proveedor.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_total", Convert.ToInt32(total.Text));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("pro_facturas", conexion, transaccion);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_descripcion", Convert.ToString(DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["descripcion"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_cantidad", Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["cantidad"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_precio", Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["precio"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_valtotal", Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["valtotal"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigo", int.Parse(codigof.Text));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

PD: el código esta como auto incremento en la BD y es foráneo en la otra ,entonces al guardar no me manda el código en la otra tbla me lo arroja como null

Comment: ya colocaste un punto de control ? en las lineas cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_total", Convert.ToInt32(total.Text));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); puedes chequear en base de datos si te grabo algo?

Comment: es que tengo que hacerlas dos con una sola transacción

Comment: @ger no,no me guarda nada

Comment: En `f_facturas` como retornas el id generado al insertar ?

Comment: yo en la función no lo agregue porque al momento de guardar me arrojaba error

Comment: Vale, como dice @LeandroTuttini, tu estas intentando guardar `codigof.Text`, que está vacio. Lo normal sería que tu procedimiento `f_facturas` devolviera un parámetro con el id del registro recien añadido, y lo pusieras en la etiqueta `codigof`

Comment: yo el código lo traigo con de esta manera ** NpgsqlCommand comand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT (codigo) FROM facturacion ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1**

Comment: pero al guardar los datos me trae el código anterior al que acabo de ingresar

Comment: Pues o bien haces esa consulta despues usar f_facturas, o mas facil pstgresql tendrá alguna función que devuelva ese valor del ultimo registro añadido, y puedes devolverlo como valor de salida del procedimiento almacenado

Comment: Podrias editar la pregunta y mencionar como son las estructuras de estas tablas? porque no me queda claro como defines los campos, hay una columna que es secuencial (identity) que se autoincrementa sola

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: ya haz utilizado codigod INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, en vez de serial?

Comment: no, con ese no he probado

Comment: pero igual como la tendría que poner en la otra tabla que es foránea

Answer (score 0):

Si defines una columna como `SERIAL` debes usar el `RETURNING`

[Using PostgreSQL SERIAL To Create Auto-increment Column](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/)

Entonces debes usar el `ExecuteScalar()`, quedando algo como esto

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("f_facturas", conexion, transaccion);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Transaction = transaccion;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_cliente", Convert.ToString(cliente.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_proveedor", Convert.ToString(proveedor.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_total", Convert.ToInt32(total.Text));
int facturaId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

NpgsqlCommand cmdDetalle = new NpgsqlCommand("pro_facturas", conexion, transaccion);
cmdDetalle.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdDetalle.Transaction = transaccion;

foreach (var row in DataGridView.Rows)
{
    cmdDetalle.Parameters.Clear();

    cmdDetalle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_descripcion", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["descripcion"].Value));
    cmdDetalle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_cantidad", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["cantidad"].Value));
    cmdDetalle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_precio", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["precio"].Value));
    cmdDetalle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_valtotal", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["valtotal"].Value));
    cmdDetalle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigo", facturaId);

    cmdDetalle.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Dentro del procedure `f_facturas` deberias tener un `INSERT` que devuelva el valor del codigo que se genere al insertar

```
INSERT INTO factura (cliente, proveedor, total) 
  VALUES (@f_cliente, @f_proveedor, @f_total) RETURNING codigo
```

Comment: me dice la consulta no tiene un destino para los datos de resultado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar Curval como alternativa a lo que dice @LeandroTuttini

```
SELECT CURRVAL(pg_get_serial_sequence('factura','codigo'))
```

Con esta instrucción obtienes el ultimo Id de la tabla factura y la asignas tu variable facturaId que va en el detalle

Comment: esto lo agregaría a la función ?

Comment: pg_get_serial_sequence  para que seria ese codigo

Comment: @Carlos cuando publicaste "yo el código lo traigo con de esta manera ** NpgsqlCommand comand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT (codigo) FROM facturacion ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1" * utilizarias el código * NpgsqlCommand comand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT CURRVAL(pg_get_serial_sequence('factura','codigo')));